# Given $x^2 - 3x +6=0$ find $x^4$ in terms of $x$.

Tags: quadratics

Could someone please explain what this question is asking? I might be able to solve it by myself by what does it mean by $x^4$? I interpret it as provide a value of $x^4$ given this quadratic so quadratic formula then raise both sides to power $4$ ? There are no real solutions to this quadratic anyway as well so I am confused.

Comment: It's a strange question.  I would guess that they mean the equation gives you a formula for $x^2$ in terms of $x$, and then you can square both sides.  You should put `$` signs around all math expressions, to make the MathJax commands effective.

Comment: Use the division algorithm $x^4=q(x)(x^2-3x+6)+rx+s=rx+s$

Comment: Might (or might not) be worth noting $x \not\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I feel like I should add that this is a poorly worded question. "In terms of $x$" usually means writing something as a *function* of $x$. So $x^4$ is clearly already in terms of $x$. Here, they seem to want $x^4$ as a *linear function* in $x$.

Comment: Ok glad I'm not the only one who was off-put

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can start from here $$x^2=3x-6$$
then multiply by $x$
$$x^3=3x^2-6x$$ now put $x^2=3x-6$ it means
$$x^3=3(3x+6)-6x=9x+18-6x$$ now you have $x^3$ in terms of x.

can you take over?

Comment: Typo:  $x^2 = 3x-6$.  Also note $x^4 = (x^2)^2 = (3x - 6)^2$

Comment: -6, just a small correction

Comment: @dmtri: thank you for your notification.

Answer (score 5):

I interpret it as

$x^2 -3x + 6 = 0$ so $x^2 = 3x -6$ so $x^4 = ????$ what?

> $x^4 = (x^2)^2 = (3x-6)^2 = 9x^2 -36x + 36$

But we aren't done.   Can we get $x^4 = ax + b$ for some $a$ and $b$?

> $x^4 = 9x^2 -36x + 36 = 9(3x-6)-36x + 36 = 27x - 54 -36x + 36=-9x -18$

Answer (score 1):

Your task is to find an equation of the form
$$x^4=f(x)$$
where $f$ has the least possible degree, given the relation $x^2-3x+6=0$. Well, we can rearrange this to $x^2=3x-6$, then square both sides to get $x^4=(3x-6)^2=9x^2-36x+36$. Substituting $x^2=3x-6$ again into this gives the final answer as $9(3x-6)-36x+36=-9x-18$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 = 3(x-2) \Rightarrow x^4 = 9(x-2)^2$

$= 9(x^2 - 4x + 4) = 9[3(x-2) - 4x + 4]$

$= 9[3x - 6 - 4x + 4] = 9[-x - 2].$